# How to initialize non-movable and non-copyable class member - boost::optional

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-optional

I have a non-movable and non-copyable type:

```
struct A
{
    A(std::string p1, int p2){}
    A(A const &) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A const &) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&) = delete;
};
```

I can construct boost optional this way:

```
boost::optional<A> op(boost::in_place("abc", 5));
```

I also need to initialize `boost::optional<A>` which is a class member. Here is my solution:

```
class B
{
public:
    B(const boost::optional<A>& op): op_(op) {} 
private:
    const boost::optional<A>& op_;
};

B b(boost::optional<A>(boost::in_place("abc", 5)));
```

Is it possible to have just `boost::optional<A>` class member and initialize it somehow ?

**Edit (clarification)**
I would like to have `boost::optional<A> op_` class data member but I don't know how to initialize it.

Comment: Do you want a data member `boost::optional<A> op_` as suggested by the last question or a data member `const boost::optional<A>& op_` as in the definition of `B`. This makes a considerable difference.

Comment: Please see Edit1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the constructor of `B` as

```
class B {
  public:
      B(std::string p1, int p2) :
         op_(boost::in_place<A>(std::move(p1), p2)) {}

  private:
    const boost::optional<A> op_;
};
```

and instantiate `B` as

```
B b("abc", 5);
```

Note that I change the data member `op_` to not be reference here, as opposed to the definition of `B` in your question.

Comment: Is it possible to create a class with variadic template constructor and forward arguments to boost::in_place ?

Comment: Yes. Use `template <class ...Args> B(Args&&... args) : op_(boost::in_place<A>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}` for that. But note that this catches _a lot_, you might want to read the corresponding item in Scott Meyer's Effective Modern C++ on that topic.